# How to cast a String value to an Enum value by Class?

Tags: java, reflection, enums

I have the following class:

```
public class EnumContainer{

    private Class<?> enumClass;
    //GET, SET

    public EnumContainer(Class<?> clazz){
        this.enumClass = clazz;
    }

    public boolean tryCast(String value){
        //Here I should try to cast the String to the Enum by enumClass field

        //return true if cast was successfull
        //false otherwise
    }
}
```

Is it even possible in Java to perform such casting?

Comment: Yes; it's `.valueOf()`.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Because I'm using hibernate and in order to simplify some mappings I need to use `@Type` annotation which reffers to the type that  have to containt the Class<?> field. From the web page I can only grab a String value.

Comment: @fge Couldn't you provide a complete answer?

Comment: @fge What object should I perform `method.invoke(obj, args)` call on?

Comment: @VinceEmigh It's not a duplicate.

Comment: You never stated you didn't have access to the actual enum.. Maybe be a little more clear in your question next time?

Comment: @VinceEmigh Since I provide the Class<?> type of that enum it should be clear that I don't have that access.

Comment: It's obviously not clear. Look at the 4 upvotes on the first comment.

Comment: This isn't casting. Stop saying casting.

Comment: @VinceEmigh You can do `valueOf` with just a Class, you just call the static method on `Enum`.

Comment: @Radiodef BTW don't you why the `enumClass.getMethod("valueOf")` method throws `NoSuchMethodException` although `enumClass.getMethods()` returns the array of `Methods` containing an instance with name `valueOf`?

Comment: @user3663882 You need something like `enumClass.getMethod("valueOf", enumClass)` because it takes a parameter. I don't really see a reason to use reflection here, though.

Comment: @Radiodef Doesn't work as well. The same excpetion is thrown.

Comment: You'd need `enumClass.getMethod("valueOf", String.class)`, my mistake. Example: [http://ideone.com/dwcbks](http://ideone.com/dwcbks).

Comment: @Radiodef Great, thank you. Now I got that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually kind of a pain because of the way `Enum` is declared. You wouldn't be able to call [`valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-) with a `Class<?>` (nor e.g. a `Class<? extends Enum<?>>`). The only way to do it without unchecked casting is to go through [`getEnumConstants`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants--):

```
public boolean tryCast(String value){
    for(Object o : enumClass.getEnumConstants()) {
        Enum<?> e = (Enum<?>) o;
        if(e.name().equals(value))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you don't care about the unchecked cast you can do:

```
try {
    Enum.valueOf( (Class) enumClass, value );
    return true;
} catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
    return false;
}
```

But, you know, some people will grumble because it's a raw type. `getEnumConstants` is probably better anyways since then you don't use exceptions for this kind of thing.

---

In addition, since you have a `Class<?>` you might want to perform a check like

```
if( !Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(enumClass) )
    return false;
```

or throw an exception in the constructor.

Comment: Well, unchecked casting is always not a very good idea... And sincee I don't know how exactly it works internally I would prefer to not using your last aaproach.

Comment: @user3663882 Then don't. I'm one of the people who grumbles so it's fine with me if you don't. ; )